# Vue v-for directive causing unexpected additional components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, nuxt-content

I am trying to use Nuxt Content to create a blog section of my website. I have created the directory structure and some testing posts. I have also created the query that grabs the posts and stores them as a ref so they can be used on the page. My issue is that the components I see on the page do not match what is returned by the Nuxt Content query

Snippet

```
<script setup> 
const { data: recentBlogPosts } = await useAsyncData(`content-${path}`, () => {
  return queryContent()
    .only(['title', 'excerpt', 'created', 'updated', 'slug', 'tags', '_id'])
    .limit(5)
    .sort({ 'updated': -1 })
    .find()
})
```

index.vue Page Snippet

```js
<nuxt-link v-for="post in recentBlogPosts" :key="post._id" :to="`blog/${post.slug}`">
  <BlogPostShort class="blog-post-short"
    :title="post.title"
    :createdDate="post.created"
    :updatedDate="post.updated"
    :excerpt="post.excerpt"
    :tags="post.tags" />
</nuxt-link>
```

The resulting website output on the page

[image]

An image of Vue DevTools showing only 5 components produced by v-for directive

[image]

I have tried adding a `:key="post._id"` to the code but that hasn't solved anything. I thought giving Nuxt a means of tying a post to the data on the backend might help it but sadly no such luck

**EDIT**
Adding image of recentBlogPosts variable added to page via mustache-syntax (not allowed to inline it because I'm a low-rep newbie):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBAJM.png

Comment: try simplifying the `:key` like use the loop `index`, it only need be unique in the for loop, I've found in the past using complex strings for keys like your `post._id` is `content:testing:TestingPost copy 2.md` can cause this

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for the suggestion. I tried using the v-for loop index for the key and sadly the issue still persists. It also persists if I remove the key entirely

Comment: when you place `<pre>{{recentBlogPosts}}</pre>` somewhere on the page is the same data as its looping though? Vue DevTools sometimes just shows what it thinks

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I've added an image to the post containing the `recentBlogPosts` variable to the page via mustache-syntax. It shows that the data is exactly what I expect, 5 posts in JSON format, so it's not an issue with my Nuxt Content query

Comment: Unless BlogPostShort can provide dupe content, it's possible there's some bug on Nuxt side. Consider providing a workable demo that can be debugged.

Comment: I don't want to sound stupid, but what would constitute a minimum example and how would you like me to host it? It's a bit tricky to host the whole content file structure. I could take the output of a vardump of "recentBlogPosts", put it in a const and then put it in a code snippet? Would that be alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appeared to be my using a v-for directive on a `<NuxtLink>` tag. The new code below works:

```html
<div v-for="post in recentBlogPosts" :key="post._id">
  <NuxtLink :to="`blog/${post.slug}`">
    <BlogPostShort class="blog-post-short"
      :title="post.title"
      :createdDate="post.created"
      :updatedDate="post.updated"
      :excerpt="post.excerpt"
      :tags="post.tags" />
  </NuxtLink>
</div>
```